# How to rotate an image using client side solution

Tags: javascript, css, image, image-manipulation, client-side

I am wondering if there is any way to dynamically rotate an image or invert an image using a client side solution? I don't care if it is plain old javascript, jquery plugin, css. I just wondered if there was some way to do this dynamically on the client side rather than having to write server side code to do for each image which I can do.

I tried searching on Google for different keywords but couldn't find anything.

EDIT: I am looking for a solution that does not require anything from HTML 5.

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968642/rotate-image-clockwise-or-anticlockwise-inside-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: Let me clarify a little because I don't want to use HTML 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox, Safari and Opera support this:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

you can also do this in IE8, maybe even 7(?):

```
position: absolute;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

rotate an element using JS:

```
var deg = 90
$('element').style.MozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
$('element').style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
```

edit:

wow, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532972%28VS.85%29.aspx the rotation works for IE 5.5!

Comment: this looks great. I will give this a try tomorrow and see how it goes.

Comment: +1 for cross browser support and `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);`

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting javascript solution:
http://www.stableflow.com/downloads/jquery-plugins/360-degrees-product-view/
Imagine that you are running some shop or blog and you present user with your products. The solution allows you to save space and present products view in very realistic form by means of the script. It allows to forget about flash (which is still not supported by all mobile devices).
What you need to utilize it is:

- Download free plugin (use link above)
- Setup the plugin using instructions
- Create and add a series of images for each product (the more images the better rotation effect you will get)
- Follow raised interest to your products from users

It really worked for me. Tested on Android mobile(lg p500), iPad and iPod touch as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the canvas element, as shown [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5514). I'm not 100% sure all browsers support it already. It is part of HTML5 (read more about it on [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Canvas_element)), so FF, Safari and Chrome support it. Not sure about IE8.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am really looking to avoid using canvas if possible. Not entirely sure it can be but that is what I am trying to figure out. I have tried searching all over Google and SO and haven't found anything yet for this. So thought I would try asking a question to see if anyone has come across this before.