# I need a javascript code for rotating images when clicked on

Tags: javascript, behavior, image-rotation

I need a javascript code for rotating images when clicked on. I would like to rotate about 5 images and have the script go back to the first image when all five images have been clicked on.

I have tried to solve this with behaviors in dreamweaver but with no sucsess. Can anyone help me with this problem! That would be great! I dont have any experience in coding.

Viktor

Comment: Welcome to the SO community, if it's not worth your time to ask the question in a well-formatted manner, what makes it worth our time to answer it?

Comment: Ah, this is a programmer's discussion forum.  If you have no experience coding, then the answers won't be of much use to you.  If you are a programmer, what you are asking about is called an "image rotator."  You can do this using the jQuery framework for javascript.  Try looking in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+image+rotator

Answer (score 1):

[Rotate image clockwise or anticlockwise inside a div using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968642/rotate-image-clockwise-or-anticlockwise-inside-a-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

?